# Android - Device ID from GCM return empty

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have to get only device id from GCM for further use. I try all but result is negative, Device id I get is empty. Please help

Here is code:

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.cmain);
    mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "registration id =====  " + regId);

    if (regId.equals("")) {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
    }
```

Logcat results :

```
I/ pushAndroidActivity (2295): registration id =====  
D/GCMRegistrar(2295): resetting backoff for shane.nuke
V/GCMRegistrar(2295): Registering app shane.nuke of senders 510772122772
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(2295): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(2295): GCM IntentService class: shane.nuke.GCMIntentService
V/GCMBaseIntentService(2295): Acquiring wakelock
```

Here is code for GCMIntentService_2

```
public class GCMIntentService_2 extends GCMBaseIntentService {

public GCMIntentService_2() {
    super(CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);
}
private static final String TAG = "===GCMIntentService===";
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    Log.e(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
}
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    Log.i(TAG, "unregistered = " + arg1);
}
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Log.i(TAG, "new message= ");
}
@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
}
@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}
```

}

Here is Mainfest.xml code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="shane.nuke"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<permission
    android:name="shane.nuke.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="shane.nuke.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="shane.nuke.second.Push"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="shane.nuke.next.GCMMessageView" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="shane.nuke" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <service android:name="shane.nuke.second.GCMIntentService_2" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: Instead of `this` use `your_activity_name.this`

Comment: FYI - errors, logcat etc. are easier to read when placed in code, instead of quote.

Comment: have you checked your `onRegistered` method of `GCMIntentService`. Log the regid from there

Comment: Show code of `GCMIntentService` code otherwise

Comment: so your not getting log message in onRegistered also

Comment: yes, i am not getting log message in onRegistered

Comment: And what about Manifest file have you make entry for permission of GCM

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="your_package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />`

    `<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`

Comment: Again i edit question and add manifest code, please check it.

Comment: And you have to define the receiver and service for GCM also in manifest

Comment: Put your `GCMIntentService_2` in your main package not in `package.second`

Comment: And add this `<uses-permission android:name="shane.nuke.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />` in your manifest

Comment: Same error still. Device id empty.

Comment: your onRegistered method is called or not because i can't see log from onRegistered method

Comment: I think it not called,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put all files in main package and use mobile data for internet. Sometime wifi not works.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

GCMRegister is deprecated use Google Cloud Messaging refer this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start.

Comment: Do you have any example for that?

Comment: Sample , just refer this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 0):

Put your GCM code in application package

Comment: Not understand, please explain in brief

Answer (score 0):

Put your GCM code in your main package(e.g "com.sample" in this case) of application  that is defined in manifest:

package="com.sample"